# Unable to scroll html

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

This is the [link](http://bctracking.surge.sh) of my website. The CSS that I am using is from [this website](https://nigelotoole.github.io/progress-tracker/)
. However, my webpage is not scrollable and my code is as follows:

```
<div> 
  <ion-grid class="container separator" *ngIf="historyList?.length > 0; else noItems">
    <ion-row style="clear:both;" class="progress-tracker progress-tracker--vertical" >
      <ion-col class="progress-step is-complete" *ngFor="let item of historyList; let i = index">
        <div class="progress-marker"></div>
        <div class="progress-text">
          <h5 class="progress-title">{{item.message}} </h5>
          <h6>by {{item.issuer}}</h6>
          <small>{{item.issueOn}}</small><br>
          <ion-button (click)="verifyCert(i)" size="small">Verify</ion-button>
        </div>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>        
  </ion-grid>
</div>
```

I have tried:

```
clear:both;
overflow: scroll;
position: relative;
```

but still not scrollable

Here is the image of my frontend
[frontend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W03Q0.png)

Comment: With what you have provided, it looks fine and not reproducible. Could you give an example to the actual site / code where the problem can be reproduced? Maybe a stackblitz?

Comment: I have updated my post with my [website](http://bctracking.surge.sh), you may click into it to see the bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest route I can see is to add a class to the parent div like so:

```
<div class="scroll"> 
  <!-- Inner Content --/>
</div>
```

And then add to your CSS:

```
.scroll {
   overflow:auto;
}
```

At least this works in Chrome with the development tools:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have checked code on the your ionic website , and as per my understanding :

you have 
**ion-grid** wrapped inside **div**

```
<div>
<ion-grid> ...</ion-grid>
</div>
```

replace your div with **ion-content , scroll will work** for you.

```
<ion-content>
<ion-grid> ...</ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

[image: scroll bar with ion-content to be used with ion-grid]